# Can you display iOS content on safari, using custom URL scheme

Tags: javascript, php, html, objective-c, url-scheme

I want to launch my app from the browser this was made possible by this code:

```
 window.location = "myApp://myparams";
```

With this i was able to open my app from browser. but with this method i leave the browser. 
I would like to know if it is possible to show you app inside the safari browser.
for example referencing my app link inside an iframe. I tried implementing the code below but didnt get the desired output.:

```
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
        frame.src = 'myApp://';
        frame.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(frame);

        // avoid unnecessary iframe on the page

        setTimeout(function() { document.body.removeChild(frame); }, 4);
```

Is there anything i am doing wrong or is it not possible using custom URL Schemes.

Comment: Short answer, no. This is not possible. A native app is not a webpage, therefore it cannot be loaded via an iframe.

Comment: You can display web view in your's application in full screen and show something inside your's web view

Comment: @Cy-4AH i get that but i wanted the other way round wanted to display it inside the website. not displaying the webpage in the app.. thanks anyway